# POST JSON generated from C# to be received by Python

Tags: json, flask, httpclient

As mentioned in the title, I attempt to

POST JSON file from C# (which is a WinForms accepting user input, then converted into a json), then to be received by python. I am quite clueless as to how to start at the C# side of the coding as I am still new to this. Would appreciate any kind help from here. Thanks

I use httpclient to communicate between the two languages, and now I would like to send the json file to the python side.

In short, the working principle of my project is:

1. User input parameters at WinForms that I have designed using C#, then these parameters are transferred over to Python by the flask and HTTPclient architecture.
2. Python process the parameters and a result is obtained, where I now wish to transfer this result back to C#, to be displayed on WinForms.

Answer (score 0):

Flask is easy to use and set up for a simple POST request like this. The flask docs are excellent: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/quickstart/#a-minimal-application

Assuming you have pip installed Flask >= v2.0, a simple flask application to receive a POST request would look like:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.post('/submit_input')
def submit_input():
    # check that your data is json
    if request.json:
        data = request.json
        # do something with the data here and create a new var...
        new_var = 'this is some new data'

    return jsonify(message=new_var)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! But what if I want to transfer a variable across the flask web, to C#? 

I assume that i would need to return the specified variable right, and to set up a GET request at C#

Comment: I've edited my answer to show how you could return a value in the response to the POST request. You could also set up a GET route in flask in addition to the POST route with the sole aim of retrieving the data. It depends on how you are storing your data on the flask side.

Comment: Yep, the problem I currently face is that I am unsure what function I should be using at C# in order to retrieve the return value (where the return value is to be displayed inside a WinForms)
Basically, the working principle of the project I am developing is
1) User input parameters at WinForms, where these parameters are sent over to Python (where the script to process the parameters are located)
2) Then the result of processing the parameters from Python is then returned, and to be sent over to C#. I am stuck at the 2nd step, as I am unsure which function to use at C#

Comment: Sorry to say i'd barely recognise c# code if it sat down next to me for lunch. Good luck

Comment: No worries about that. Your guidance has definitely help me in order to better understand the flask architecture. Likewise to you, stay safe my friend